# Is mmap + madvise really a form of async I/O?

Tags: c++, c, linux, asynchronous, mmap

I'm trying to figure out if `mmap`'ing a file, and then using `madvise()` or `posix_madvise()` with `MADV_WILLNEED`/`POSIX_MADV_WILLNEED` actually triggers background async I/O for read-ahead.  The [man pages for `madvise`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) don't specify whether this is the case - the actual behavior of `madvise` is left mostly unclear, in order to allow for flexibility of the implementation.

But does any actual mainstream POSIX implementation (like Linux) actually perform async file I/O when `madvise()` with `MADV_WILLNEED` is called?  I can't seem to get any reliable information about this.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407542/is-there-really-no-asynchronous-block-i-o-on-linux) suggests it does, on Linux at least, even if it is not ideal since there is no callback mechanism.

This [book excerpt](https://books.google.com/books?id=K1vXEb1SgawC&pg=PA117&lpg=PA117&dq=madvise%20readahead&source=bl&ots=fdC_L7AUUF&sig=7UAVqpfgH1qA2XomyGaWeeE152g&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oiOXVfq6H4Oo-QGS5IGIBg&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q=madvise%20readahead&f=false) claims that `posix_fadvise` with `POSIX_FADV_WILLNEED` will do asynchronous read ahead, but doesn't mention if `madvise()` does async read ahead.

Furthermore, it would seem that the whole concept of "read-ahead" I/O doesn't really make any sense unless it's asynchronous.  If it was synchronous, it simply makes the user application block for the read-ahead, instead of later when actually reading the file, which doesn't seem like a particularly powerful optimization.

So, does `madvise()` with `MADV_WILLNEED` actually do async read-ahead on any mainstream platform (like Linux)?

Comment: In answer to the question posed in your title, no, I don't think it reasonable to characterize `mmap()` + `madvise()` as a form of async I/O, since the kernel is not *obligated* to do anything whatsoever in response to an `madvise()` call specifying `MADV_WILLNEED` (unlike when the advice is `MADV_DONTNEED`).  As for whether any system actually will perform async readahead under any circumstances, I am inclined to suppose that some will, but I cannot provide any details.

Comment: A note of nitpickery: Non-blocking synchronous functions don't block, and aren't asynchronous, but are rationalised to solve the same kind of problems as asynchronous functions.

Answer (score 2):

With Linux you can always check the source code.

See [fadvise.c](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/mm/fadvise.c#L99):

```
case POSIX_FADV_WILLNEED:
    ...
    force_page_cache_readahead(mapping, f.file, start_index,
                   nrpages);
    break;
```

So `posix_fadvise` calls `force_page_cache_readahead` to perform readahead.

Now lets look at [madvise.c](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/mm/madvise.c#L273):

```
static long madvise_willneed(...)
{
    ...
    force_page_cache_readahead(file->f_mapping, file, start, end-start);
    return 0;
}
```

So `MADV_WILLNEED` and `POSIX_FADV_WILLNEED` are equivalent on Linux.

Can this be called asynchronous I/O? I don't think so. Async IO usually implies there is some notification that allows you to retrieve data. Advise is just an advise: not only you do not know when data is ready to be read, but if you are too late, data might be thrown away already.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should assume that the m* functions won't perform async readahead.