Why asynchrounous read/write has less performance than conventioal read/write
In chapter 14-5 of APUE (Asynchrounous I/O), there exist two sample codes. One using conventional read/write and another using asynchrounous read/write (figures 14-20 & 14-21 respectively)
I test both of them (on linux Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS) by 0.5GB input data file. But, asynchrounous version takes about 14sec and conventional take 12sec !
My question is : why asynchrounous version takes more than conventioal one?
(by strace I see many futex system calls in asynchrounous version)
Conventional version is as follows:
#include "apue.h"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define BSZ 4096
unsigned char buf[BSZ];
unsigned char

translate(unsigned char c) {
  if (isalpha(c)) {
    if (c >= 'n')
      c -= 13;
    else if (c >= 'a')
      c += 13;
    else if (c >= 'N')
      c -= 13;
    else
      c += 13;
  }
  return(c);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int ifd, ofd, i, n, nw;

  if (argc != 3)
    err_quit("usage: rot13 infile outfile");
  if ((ifd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) < 0)
    err_sys("can't open %s", argv[1]);
  if ((ofd = open(argv[2], O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, FILE_MODE)) < 0)
    err_sys("can't create %s", argv[2]);

  while ((n = read(ifd, buf, BSZ)) > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      buf[i] = translate(buf[i]);
    
    if ((nw = write(ofd, buf, n)) != n) {
      if (nw < 0)
        err_sys("write failed");
      else
        err_quit("short write (%d/%d)", nw, n);
    }
  }
  
  fsync(ofd);
  exit(0);
}

and asynchrounous version is as follows:
#include "apue.h"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <aio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define BSZ 4096
#define NBUF 8

enum rwop {
  UNUSED = 0,
  READ_PENDING = 1,
  WRITE_PENDING = 2
};

struct buf {
  enum rwop op;
  int last;
  struct aiocb aiocb;
  unsigned char data[BSZ];
};

struct buf bufs[NBUF];

unsigned char
translate(unsigned char c) {
/* same as before */
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int ifd, ofd, i, j, n, err, numop;
  struct stat sbuf;
  const struct aiocb *aiolist[NBUF];
  off_t off = 0;

  if (argc != 3)
    err_quit("usage: rot13 infile outfile");
  if ((ifd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) < 0)
    err_sys("can't open %s", argv[1]);
  if ((ofd = open(argv[2], O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, FILE_MODE)) < 0)
    err_sys("can't create %s", argv[2]);
  if (fstat(ifd, &sbuf) < 0)
    err_sys("fstat failed");

  /* initialize the buffers */
  for (i = 0; i < NBUF; i++) {
    bufs[i].op = UNUSED;
    bufs[i].aiocb.aio_buf = bufs[i].data;
    bufs[i].aiocb.aio_sigevent.sigev_notify = SIGEV_NONE;
    aiolist[i] = NULL;
  }

  numop = 0;
  for (;;) {
    for (i = 0; i < NBUF; i++) {
      switch (bufs[i].op) {
        case UNUSED:
          /*
          * Read from the input file if more data
          * remains unread.
          */
          if (off < sbuf.st_size) {
             bufs[i].op = READ_PENDING;
             bufs[i].aiocb.aio_fildes = ifd;
             bufs[i].aiocb.aio_offset = off;
             off += BSZ;
             if (off >= sbuf.st_size)
                bufs[i].last = 1;
             bufs[i].aiocb.aio_nbytes = BSZ;
             if (aio_read(&bufs[i].aiocb) < 0)
                err_sys("aio_read failed");
             aiolist[i] = &bufs[i].aiocb;
             numop++;
          }
          break;

        case READ_PENDING:
          if ((err = aio_error(&bufs[i].aiocb)) == EINPROGRESS)
             continue;
          if (err != 0) {
            if (err == -1)
            err_sys("aio_error failed");
            else
            err_exit(err, "read failed");
          }
          /*
          *Aread is complete; translate the buffer
          * and write it.
          */
          if ((n = aio_return(&bufs[i].aiocb)) < 0)
            err_sys("aio_return failed");
          if (n != BSZ && !bufs[i].last)
            err_quit("short read (%d/%d)", n, BSZ);
          for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            bufs[i].data[j] = translate(bufs[i].data[j]);
  
          bufs[i].op = WRITE_PENDING;
          bufs[i].aiocb.aio_fildes = ofd;
          bufs[i].aiocb.aio_nbytes = n;
          if (aio_write(&bufs[i].aiocb) < 0)
            err_sys("aio_write failed");
          /* retain our spot in aiolist */
          break;

        case WRITE_PENDING:
          if ((err = aio_error(&bufs[i].aiocb)) == EINPROGRESS)
            continue;
          if (err != 0) {
            if (err == -1)
              err_sys("aio_error failed");
            else
              err_exit(err, "write failed");
          }
          /*
          *Awrite is complete; mark the buffer as unused.
          */
          if ((n = aio_return(&bufs[i].aiocb)) < 0)
            err_sys("aio_return failed");
          if (n != bufs[i].aiocb.aio_nbytes)
            err_quit("short write (%d/%d)", n, BSZ);
          aiolist[i] = NULL;
          bufs[i].op = UNUSED;        
          numop--;
          break;
        }
      }
      
      if (numop == 0) {
        if (off >= sbuf.st_size)
          break;
      } else {
        if (aio_suspend(aiolist, NBUF, NULL) < 0)
          err_sys("aio_suspend failed");
      }
  }
  bufs[0].aiocb.aio_fildes = ofd;
  if (aio_fsync(O_SYNC, &bufs[0].aiocb) < 0)
     err_sys("aio_fsync failed");
  
  exit(0);
} 


Is your "asynchronous io" being done by threads spawned by glibc to do synchronous IO?  Run your test program under strace with a command something like  strace -f -o /path/to/output ./testAIO and see if there are new threads created that are merely doing basic synchronous [p]read()/[p]write() calls.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407542/is-there-really-no-asynchronous-block-i-o-on-linux for more details.
